# 'The resource cannot be found' only in firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I have an asp.net project with asp buttons. It successfully runs in IE11. But, in firefox, when i click the button it says 'The resource cannot be found.HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. '

Little bit help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: What resource cannot be found?

Comment: Requested URL: /DUDG/checkin/InvoiceNotes.aspx

Comment: FF sometimes caches specific routes, try to clear its cache. Is this error occurring in another browsers(Chrome e.g.) also?

Comment: yeah i have tried that. still no luck. actually, this it is not compatible in chrome.